# Displaying column names at the top in MDX like in SQL

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to display the column name on top in MDX query.

Below is the Result of my MDX query. I want to display the Year column name at the top (Marked in Red)

```
blank     amount(Measure)
ALL       1000  
2010      500    
2011      500
```

In above blank section, I want to display the attribute name of the dimension i.e. YEAR.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This information is available in the result that is coming back as answer to the MDX query, no matter if you get it back in multidimensional or in tabular form.

But what is displayed is totally dependent on the tool displaying the data.

Comment: I am using Sql server management studio to check the results. Is it possible to display the column name in management studio

Comment: No, as the developers of Management Studio decided not to display this information.